# Compile Conditionals - Best Practices

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm unit testing with console apps.  So, anywhere I want to unit test i'm using compile conditionals like so

```
#if UnitTest
                    Console.WriteLine("Invoke: Method 1 Result");
#endif
```

This works great, but it makes for messy and ugly code.  How bad would it be, how much of a resource hit would it be, for me to invoke something like below.

```
    public static class UnitTest
    {
        public static void Add(string value)
        {
#if UnitTest
            Console.WriteLine(value);
#endif
        }
    }
```

and then, when ever I want to place a unit test, i simply call.

```
UnitTest.Add("Invoke: Method 1 Result");
```

Comment: Obviously, i'd be calling a method that does nothing.  But that can't be too heavy, It feels dirty though.

Comment: Sorry, maybe not related to the actual question - but why not to write unit tests which will automatically tell you is code correct and where you can log staff in the console as much as you want

Answer (score 4):

You are *so close*.

The right way to do this is

```
public static class UnitTest
{
  [Conditional("UnitTest")]
  public static void Log(string s)
  {
    Console.WriteLine(s);
  }
}
```

The compiler will remove all calls to `UnitTest.Log()` in source code where `UnitTest` is not defined.

> Obviously, i'd be calling a method that does nothing.

That's the nice thing about the conditional attribute. The compiler *removes the call entirely*.

Incidentally, this is how `Debug.Assert` works. If `DEBUG` is not defined, the assertion is removed entirely.

This has the benefit of not littering your release version with calls to empty methods. It has the downside that if you are debugging the release version, you cannot put breakpoints on the removed methods. Also, remember that side effects are also removed; never do:

```
Debug.Assert(++x == 10);
```

Because the `++x` will not happen in the release version but will in the debug version.

Speaking of which, you might wonder, can I do this?

```
class C { 
  #if UnitTest
    static int counter = 0;
  #endif
  ...
  UnitTest.Log("Logger logged " + (++counter) + " logs!");
```

**Give that some thought**. Should this work, or not? Remember, *reason like the compiler writer*.

Once you think you know what the compiler should do here, check your answer:

https://ericlippert.com/2009/09/10/whats-the-difference-between-conditional-compilation-and-the-conditional-attribute/

Comment: The cost of calling an empty method is not really the concern here.  In the unlikely event that it doesn't get optimized out, it's still unlikely to have performance costs.  The real value of a conditional method is that the parameters' expressions don't need to be resolved to values when calling the method.

Comment: @Matthew: You're welcome. If your question was answered, please mark it as answered so that no one else wastes time looking at an already-answered question.